# Algo falla en las variables tipoManyToManyField

Tags: django

Para mi proyecto he creado en mi proyecto un nuevo modelo llamado desplazamiento, que se relacionará con el modelo animal mediante una variable tipo `manytomanyfield`:

```
class desplazamiento(models.Model):
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    descripcion=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    foto=models.ImageField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class animal(models.Model):
    ncomun=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ncientifico=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    foto=models.ImageField()
    categoria=models.ForeignKey(categoria,null=True)
    alimentacion=models.ForeignKey(alimentacion,null=True)
    desplazamiento=models.ManyToManyField(desplazamiento)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ncomun
```

Lo siguiente es que en el formulario para hacer un nuevo animal se adapte a la nueva variable:

```
class nue_animal(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = animal
        fields = ('ncomun', 'ncientifico', 'foto', 'categoria', 'alimentacion', 'desplazamiento')
```

Código **views.py**:

```
def nuevo_animal(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = nue_animal(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            com = form.cleaned_data['ncomun']
            cie = form.cleaned_data['ncientifico']
            fot = form.cleaned_data['foto']
            cat = form.cleaned_data['categoria']
            ali = form.cleaned_data['alimentacion']
            des = form.cleaned_data['desplazamiento']
            an = animal(ncomun=com, ncientifico=cie, foto=fot, categoria=cat, alimentacion=ali, desplazamiento=des)
            an.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form=nue_animal()
    return render(request,'bestias.html',{'forma':form})
```

Así consigo añadir la variable al formulario, pero cuando le doy a `insertar`, me sale esto:

> needs to have a value for field "animal" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

PD: El `Jabali` es el nombre (`ncomun`) del nuevo animal. Por el contrario, si inserto el animal mediante el administrador, todo sale bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es sencillo, pero te recomiendo primero siempre buscar las documentaciones de los software que uses, [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) te dejo la de *ManyToManyFields*.

Lo primero es más una recomendación, cuando uses `ModelForm` en tus formularios, recuerda que ellos vienen un método llamado `save` con el cual no tendrías que preocuparte con los guardados de campos `ManyToMany` ya que el lo hace automáticamente, un ejemplo para tu caso sería hacer lo siguiente:

```
form = nue_animal(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    animal = form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Y listo, solucionado el problema, ahora, si lo que quieres es manipular la instancia con datos propios y este modelo contiene campos `ManyToMany`, entonces harías así:

```
form = nue_animal(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    animal = form.save(commit=False)
    # hago algo con mi instancia
    animal.owner = request.user  # un ejemplo
    animal.save()
    form.save_m2m()  # importante esta linea para guardar los *ManyToManyFields*
return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Y otra opción es seguir como estas haciendo, crear la instancia manualmente, solo tendrías que seguir este orden:

```
form = nue_animal(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    com = form.cleaned_data['ncomun']
    cie = form.cleaned_data['ncientifico']
    fot = form.cleaned_data['foto']
    cat = form.cleaned_data['categoria']
    ali = form.cleaned_data['alimentacion']
    des = form.cleaned_data['desplazamiento']
    an = animal(
       ncomun=com, ncientifico=cie, foto=fot,
       categoria=cat, alimentacion=ali
    )
    an.save()
    for desplazamiento in des:
        an.desplazamiento.add(desplazamiento)  # esta es la forma de agregar objetos manualmente a un ManyToMany
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Cualquier duda o pregunta, comenta, espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Pues ha funcionado. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, tienes la opción de permitir que el campo desplazamiento tenga valores null, en el modelo quedaría así.

```
desplazamiento=models.ManyToManyField(desplazamiento, blank=True)
```

Comment: Pues el error sigue ahi. Voy a editar para incluir más información.